# What are the biggest software pains for graphic designers?

Tags: software-recommendation

What are your biggest software grips as a graphic designer? Some examples might be software that:

- is unnecessarily complicated
- doesn't allow you to accomplish what you really want to do
- doesn't have very good documentation or customer support
- crashes or malfunctions

**Why I'm Asking**

I'm doing some preliminary anecdotal research into how software limitations limit the creativity of creative professionals. I thought I'd ask here to see what kind of response I'd get.

Comment: This is a "list" question. Why do you need to know what the biggest complaints are? Are you trying to solve them? Are you looking for reasons not to become a graphic designer?

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained why I wanted this information.  I'm doing some preliminary anecdotal research into how software limitations limit the creativity of creative professionals.  I thought I'd ask here to see what kind of response I'd get.

Comment: Can you please edit the question to reflect this ^^ comment?

Comment: When you say, "limit the creativity", do you mean that generally - anything stopping a creative professional getting stuff done - or do you mean specifically software problems making people less creative by the literal meaning of the word: less able to come up with innovative or original ideas? I can't think of any software issue that limits *creativity* in that sense (except maybe the fact that internet explorer exists). Creativity in the strict sense is generally best done away from or not depending on the computer.

Comment: @Lauren Ipsum Absolutely.

Comment: @user568458 What I mean is something that degrades your ability to create what you invision.  An architect might want to walk through a 3D version of a building while they're working on it.  What if the software only supported 2d views of it?  I would consider that limiting the architect's creativity because the software impedes his or her thought process.

Comment: This question could use some refinement.  Gripes and annoyances are not the same as technical limitations - and [listing gripes really isn't a good fit for this site](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask).  It feels like there might be an interesting question underneath, but it needs to be edited.

Answer (score 4):

- Cost for upgrades given that they always have bugs. (Adobe)
- Release cycles which focus on revenue rather than delivering solid products. (Adobe)
- no printed manuals (Adobe)
- feature sets which are years behind competitors (Adobe and Quark)
- Poor integration when multiple apps are form the same company (Adobe)
- Feature sets targeted and a very, very, very small percentage of users (Adobe & Quark)
- Tech and customer support located in a non-native-English speaking countries. (any)
- Moronic "cloud" delivery of software driven by media hype and revenue greed, not driven by user demands (Adobe).
- Lack of customer loyalty. Most businesses appreciate a customer who's been a steady revenue stream for years or decades and they offer those customers special rewards. Not software vendors. They have the "one and done' mindset even though a customer may spend tens of thousands of dollars on their software over their career.
- Customer incentives decreasing while software costs increase. There was a time when you received all sorts of goodies for your thousand dollar purchase - manuals, fonts, artwork, t-shirts, a nice aluminum tin with discs, etc. Now you get none of that but the software costs more.
- Licensing hoops. I realize piracy is a problem. But has any of the licensing features prevented it? Not from what I see. All it does is force legitimate customers to jump through hoops generally at less-than-optimal times - like with a deadline looming.

Comment: Typo: *form* should be *from*. (Also, your full stops come sometimes after the parenthesis, sometimes before, and sometimes are missing altogether. Yes, I know I'm being petty.)

Answer (score 3):

Anything by Adobe due to:

- their business model revolves around perpetual beta releases disguised as 'upgrades'
- bloatware
- they buy companies and kill their good software products (I'll never forgive them for killing Freehand, even though I realize Macromedia had a large part in that too...)
- Acrobat Reader

I could go on.

I half kid. They do make good software and they are an industry standard for many good reasons as well as the few bad ones.

As a web designer, anything by Microsoft due to:

- inventing sharepoint
- inventing IE

Comment: Ha ha. If someone put you in charge of Adobe and told you you could make the world a better place for graphic designers, what would you do differently?

Answer (score 0):

Crashes! The worst that can happen is that you loose all the work of a productive day... :_(

Comment: And, closely related, file corruption, which can happen frustratingly often.

Comment: Do software crashes happen frequently for you? What operating system/software do you normally work with? Is file corruption also common?

Comment: Precisely, Photoshop CS6 crashed yesterday twice, and now Flash CS5 crashes every time I try to work with a file (Windows 7)

Comment: Related "[Which version of Adobe Flash is the stablest?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/10542/which-version-of-adobe-flash-is-the-stablest)"

Answer (score 0):

Besides licensing models, which is always tricky, my biggest gripe has to do with annoying bugs. We all know bugs are a fact of software, but bugs can waste more designers time then anything else. Now-a-days with YouTube one can quickly figure out how to do this or that without a manual, but when something does not work as advertised, that is a big time-sucker for me, especially on the video production side.

Peace - David