# Which version of Adobe Flash is the stablest?

Tags: software-recommendation, adobe-flash

The artist in our company has a lot of problems (crashes, corrupted files...) with Adobe Flash CS5 (last patches installed). It's really a pain in the neck...

With Flash CS4 the situation was not better...

Is CS6 stabler? Which version do you prefer?

Comment: This is a trick question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its depend wat you want from flash. I'm using flash from past 10yrs and used almost all the versions of flash. I love flash 8 but not i moved to CS4 because of AS3 support. I felt if you do only animation related work then flash 8 is the one of the best in all the versions.

Flash CS4 and CS5 and after that all versions are bulky and hangs often. Again if your project file is heavy or library is not clean then also flash crash.

Comment: Is there any way to clean a library?

Comment: @Dani Personally I also think Macromedia Flash 8 as a tool was very stable and pretty fast. With newer version I also recommend keeping a clean .fla file in general. Regarding cleaning the library, the easiest option is to use the **Select Unused Items** option from the Library panel's context menu.

Answer (score 0):

Its not that which version is stable or not. It depends which you use. May be a pirated one leads into a problem and such issues you prefer.